# HTTP Request Referer in Meteor Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a server side route in my Meteor app where I can get, for instance, the client's IP:

```
this.route('foo', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/bar',
    action: function () {
      var ip = context.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    }
  });
```

How can I access the [referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14) field? Do I need to use [Meteor Headers](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-headers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly access the connect request object, which has the headers:

`this.request.headers['referer']`

Like this:

```js
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('foo', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '/bar',
        action: function () {
            console.log("All headers:", this.request.headers);
            console.log("Referer:", this.request.headers['referer']);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This returns `undefined` for me using curl/Chrome/Safari. My headers object contains lots of other stuff (host, connection, user agent, etc.) What could be the problem?

Comment: well, is there a referer? That header is not always set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer. Did you open `/bar` via a link, or by entering that URL into the address bar?

Comment: Either way, it's undefined.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with meteor or iron-router then.  I use the above code in production and it works fine. Another thing you can test is what you get if the meteor app runs in an iframe in a different page. I that case you should be getting the framing page as referrer if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and after some more digging I figured out if the source page was secure (HTTPS) the browser will not send the referer.

As well if the source document is on the local computer a referer is not available. That fooled me for a while as I simply created a `test.html` on the Desktop for testing...

So the code in my route for blocking direct requests to this route from other websites looks like this now:

```
action: function () {
  var self = this;
  var host = self.request.headers.host;
  var referer = self.request.headers.referer;
  var regex = new RegExp("^http(?:s)?://" + host);

  if(typeof self.request.headers.referer !== "undefined" && !regex.test(referer)) {
    Meteor.log.error("Access blocked from " + referer);
    self.response.statusCode = 403;
    self.response.end(Handlebars.templates['403']());
    return;
  }
}
```

**If** the referer is set, it has to match the current hostname.

Answer (score 1):

you can do document.referrer to get that information

alternatively you can use History API:
history.go(-1);